# Ruby on Rails - Possible to eager load within a .map() method?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, eager-loading

Is it possible to use eager loading as part of a .map() method?

For example, I have the following:

`tag_images = tags.map(&:images)`

And elsewhere, each of those tag_images has its parent_image accessed with `image.parent_image`.

The bullet gem is advising I use `.includes(:parent_image)`, but I'm not sure how to apply eager loading in this situation.

Here is how the applicable parts of the models are set up...

**Image.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags
has_many :tags, through: :image_tags

has_many :crops, class_name: "Image", foreign_key: "parent_image_id"
belongs_to :parent_image, class_name: "Image"
```

**Tag.rb**

```
has_many :image_tags
has_many :images, through: :image_tags
```

What's going on is that it is going through a series of one or more tags and "collecting" all of the images associated with them (thus the use of `tags.map(&:images)`). And later on, the `parent_image` for each of those images is referenced with `image.parent_image`.

So ideally, while it's going through to "collect" the `tag_images`, is there a way it could 'get' the associated parent_images while it's already in there during the initial `.map` method (or perhaps some other query that is more suitable)?

Any ideas?

Comment: Are you sure you want to use `map`? (It's a method, btw, and not a 'command'.) It seems like you might want to use a query, but you don't show any info about your models, so it's hard to tell.

Comment: Of course, sorry @jvillian, I went back and added in the model information. Does that help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you have a variable `tags` that contains an `enumerble` of `Tag`s (like an `ActiveRecord_Relation`), I think you might want something more like:

```
tag_images = Image.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tags}).distinct.includes(:parent_image)
```

You may or may not need that `.distinct` - you'll just have to mess with it to see.

BTW, you can check the [Specifying Conditions on the Joined Tables](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_querying.html#specifying-conditions-on-the-joined-tables) docs to learn more about that `.joins(:tags).where(tags: {id: tags})` bit.

Comment: Thank you @jvillian, that does exactly what I need!

Answer (score 0):

If you write it as what Bullet suggested `tag_images = tags.includes(:parent_image)`, that will eager load the included associations and add them in memory. If you call parent_image on any tag instances, it will not fire off any additional queries.

Comment: It seems like `parent_image` is an association on `Image`, no? (Hard to say, really, since the OP omits model information.) In which case `tags.includes(:parent_image)` may not work, yes?

Comment: Hello @user6500179! I went back and added in the model information to my question. Would you mind taking a second look? Thanks again for your help!